# Opening Test File on Cisco IOSXE python guestshell

Tags: python, automation, cisco-ios

I successfully transferred a text file (zero_conf.txt) to a Cisco IOSXE (Amsterdam) switch flash file system using python on the guestshell.

However when I try to open the text file using the following code:

```py
with open('/flash/zero_conf.txt','r+') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
```

I am getting the following error:

> with open('/flash/zero_conf.txt','r+') as f:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/flash/zero_conf.txt'

Please let me know if I am making a syntax error or what will be the correct way to open a text file on the Cisco iosxe python guestshell.